# Ubuntu 16.04 : Nautilus doesn't club windows from mounted drives

Tags: unity, 16.04, mount, nautilus

I have installed 16.04 on my system. I have two external drives which are mounted. Before, whenever I would open those windows, it would show me in the single Nautilus window which is by default on top in Unity application bar. Now, I have to click on the mounted drives which are shown at the bottom. Somehow clubbing them into the single Nautilus is disabled. How can I club them, so I just have to click on Nautilus icon instead of individual drives. Nautilus version : `3.14.3` Below is the screenshot :

[image]

I hope the problem is clear. If not, kindly let me know. Thank you,.